# Is there a way to make intelliJ idea display folding toggles for "if" statement?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I'm using `intelliJ` IDEA and by default, it displays a pair of folding toggles for methods and `javadoc` comments, but not "if", "for" or "while" statements:

I wonder if there is a way to display toggles for all the code blocks surrounded by braces?

PS: too bad that I cannot upload an image. Hope you can understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: So frustrating... IDEA supports such "folds" for Javascript, but not for Java.

Answer (score 16):

You can fold any code block with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (also available in the Code → Folding menu).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (same menu) folds a selection.

(Use <kbd>⌘</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on OSX.)

Comment: Thanks. However i found using the keys is still a little inconvenience. What i want is  to show toggles by default for all the code blocks. When I'm going through the code, I can easily fold any if or for blocks by clicking the toggles. I don't know if intelliJ IDEA support this feature.